# Inaccessible cardinals under a Mahlo

Tags: set-theory, large-cardinals

Is it true the statement that: if $\kappa$ is a Mahlo cardinal, then for all $\alpha<\kappa$ there is a cardinal $\lambda$ with $\alpha<\lambda<\kappa$ and $\lambda$ contains $\lambda$-many inaccessible cardinals?

It seems really obvious to me, but I tried to prove it and it feels a bit odd.

Comment: Please add context and attempts to this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is true. Here's one way to show this.

**Lemma.** If $\lambda$ is inaccessible, then $\lambda$ is the $\lambda$th inaccessible if and only if the set of inaccessible cardinals below $\lambda$ is unbounded if and only if $V_\lambda\models$"There is a proper class of inaccessible cardinals".

This lemma is easy enough to prove, so I will leave you to work it out.

**Exercise.** If $\kappa$ is Mahlo, then $\kappa$ is the $\kappa$th inaccessible cardinal.

Now, show that $C=\{\alpha<\kappa\mid (V_\alpha,\in)\prec (V_\kappa,\in)\}$ is a club, where $\prec$ means "elementary submodel" in the language of set theory. And now that "There is a proper class of inaccessible cardinals" is a first-order statement in the language of set theory.

Finally, since $\kappa$ is Mahlo, the inaccessible cardinals below it form a stationary set, so $\{\lambda\in C\mid\lambda\text{ is inaccessible}\}$ is a stationary set as well as the intersection of a club and a stationary set. In particular, it is unbounded. Now, apply the lemma.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer! It was really helpful for me to understand better the objects in question. I think I proved everything you said, except for one thing: how can I prove that $C$ is a club? Maybe it’s some general result that I don’t recall, but it feels to me that my problem is concentrated in that point. Thank you a lot again!!

Comment: If you liked the answer, it would be nice to mark it as correct @alvoi

Comment: @alvoi: Well, do you know that the increasing union of elementary submodels is an elementary submodel? That takes care of the closed part. To show that it's unbounded, simply iterate Löwenheim–Skolem by starting with some $V_{\alpha_0}$, taking the elementary submodel it generates, letting $\alpha_1$ be the supremum of the ordinals of that model, and adjoining $V_{\alpha_n}$ recursively. The limit will be of the form $V_\alpha$.

Comment: @AsafKaragila ooh yeah, you're right! I felt like Löwenheim-Skolem was needed but I didn't think of applying it that way! Thank you, you are always perfectly clear!